# Insert text before submitting HTML button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a button that calls an ajax once you submit but I need to add another input where you have to enter text and if that text is the same as the text found in the DB this button should execute the AJAX. How can this be done?

**This is my AJAX code:**

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery(".canjear").click(function(e){
        if(this.tagName==="A"){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&task=miscuponess.canjearCupon",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id:jQuery(this).data("id")},
            success: window.location.href = "index.php?option=com_cuphoneo&view=miscuponess&layout=default"
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**This is my PHP/HTML button:**

```
<div class="panel-boton-canjear">
            <?php 
                foreach($campos_extra as $value){
                    if($value->id == 17){
                        if(!empty($value->value)){
            ?>              
                            <input class="canjear btn" type="button" value="<?php echo JText::_('COM_CUPHONEO_BOTON_CANJEAR'); ?>" data-id="<?php echo $valor->item_id; ?>" />
            <?php 
                        }
                    }
                }
            ?>
</div>
```

Comment: "I have a button that is called by ajax once you submit" - first line itself is confusing. Your button is added after a successful ajax request..? or are you sending an ajax request upon clicking a button..? "if that text is the same as the text found in the DB this button should execute the AJAX" for checking the value in DB, probably you've   to send an ajax req right..? can you be more specific..

Comment: @TJ Im sending an ajax request upon subbmitting the button and the value in the database is the variable `$value->value` which in my if statement, this means that this value can be empty if it wasnt filled in which if so no text box should popup for you to enter the value but if this was filled in previously a text box should appear for you to put in the same value and if this same value is correct the ajax request should be called.